# Filter dataframe based on duplicate entries conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with entries that are repeated due to revisions. I am trying to filter them out by their "status".
For example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = pd.DataFrame( { 'Item':['Submission#1','Submission#1','Submission#2','Su
bmission#2','Submission#2','Submission#3','Submission#3'], 'Revision' : [0,1,0,1
,2,0,1], 'Status' : ['R','A','R','P','A','R','P']} )
>>> d
           Item  Revision Status
0  Submission#1         0      R
1  Submission#1         1      A
2  Submission#2         0      R
3  Submission#2         1      P
4  Submission#2         2      A
5  Submission#3         0      R
6  Submission#3         1      P
```

I want to keep the "Submissions" which are still "P" (pending) in their latest revision. "Submission#3" entries will only be recorded as "Submission#1" has been approved on the latest revision and "Submission#2" tho pending in "Revision" 1, was approved on "Revision" 2.

Result:

```
           Item  Revision Status
5  Submission#3         0      R
6  Submission#3         1      P
```

Could anyone guide me on how to filter data by looking for other instances of their entries, finding all "Revisions" made and selecting them based on the latest status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use groupby and isin based on boolean indexing i.e

```
new = d.loc[d.groupby('Item')['Revision'].idxmax()]

#         Item  Revision Status
#1  Submission#1         1      A
#4  Submission#2         2      A
#6  Submission#3         1      P

sub = new[new['Status'] == 'P']['Item']

#6    Submission#3
#Name: Item, dtype: object

late = d[d['Item'].isin(sub)]
```

Output late :

```
          Item  Revision Status
5  Submission#3         0      R
6  Submission#3         1      P
```